# How to output an RFC-822 compatible date string with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, date, rss

I'm using Node.js to build my RSS file. I create a Date string with `(new Date).toString()` and then use that value for the `<pubDate>` field in the RSS file. However, when I run the [Feed Validator](http://feedvalidator.org), it reports that such a date string is not valid:

[image]

An example Date string that I generate is:

```
Fri Oct 25 2013 17:59:42 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)
```

If I understand correctly, in order to validate, there should be a comma after "Fri", and the "GMT" and the parens at the end should be removed. Is there an built-in way to produce such compliant strings with JavaScript or will I have to write a custom function to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`(new Date).toUTCString()`

Documented at http://mdn.io/toUTCString

Comment: Checks out. Thanks. The URL is `mdn.io/toUTCString` btw :p

Comment: Thanks, didn't know there was a short version

Comment: To everyone who is actually looking for RFC822. This is not it as it is `Based on rfc7231 and modified according to ecma-262 toUTCString, it can have negative values in the 2021 version`

Comment: thanks, it's help me to generate date timne for rss feed